# Why do I get an error when I add a border for every side, and then assign only one side?

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

As you see I write:

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

then remove only the right border:

```
border: 1px solid red;
border-right-width: 0;
```

because I don't want to write:

```
border-top: 1px solid red;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
border-left: 1px solid red;
```

But I get an error:
[wrong scss code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgxdV.jpg)
recommendation:
[recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwJ0a.png)
ide decision:
[ide decision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eAfx.png)
And I don't understand why.
Webstorm says that I should keep only
`border: $border;` or `border-right-width: 0;`
not two lines of code at the same time.

But if I write like this:

```
border: 1px solid red;
border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
```

[good scss code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdnGd.jpg)

It says that it's ok. I don't understand Why is it ok but border-right-with not?

I also tried `border-right: 0;` but it says that it's the wrong code too.

Comment: does it work? if yes, then it's good.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat yourself, you could go longhand: `border-color: red; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;`. As for what's "right" and "wrong", your editor isn't the best guide. If it's valid CSS and works, it's okay to use. Otherwise it's a matter of style, preference and opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering in WebStorm regarding your SCSS code is related to a recommendation or decision made by the IDE's code analysis tool and actually, it's not the scss compiler error. It suggests that you should choose either `border: $border;` or `border-right-width: 0;`, but not have both lines of code simultaneously. This recommendation is due to the conflicting nature of `border` and `border-right-width` properties, as both affect the overall border appearance.